# Prevent scan() from removing quotations or quotes

Tags: r

I have a folder full of xml files from powerpoint with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

I was hoping to scan the files and just replace one of these items with stringr and then cat() back to the file:

```
a <- scan(file="slide10.xml.rels",what = "raw",sep = "@")
b <- str_replace_all(a,pattern = "1.0",replacement = "2.0")
cat(b,file="testcat.xml.rels")
```

The problem is, everytime I scan the contents of the file into R, all of the quotation marks dissapear and lines like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

turn into:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=yes?>
```

which breaks the xml file.
Can I do this with scan() or do I have to start using an xml reader?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you use a package like *XML*

Comment: I guess you could use `readLines()` something like `cat(sub("1", "2", readLines("file.xml", warn = FALSE)), file = filename)`

Comment: how about quote = NULL